# Как перезаписать определенную строку в определенном файле?

Tags: php

Возникла довольно трудная для моего опыта в `php` задача, с которой мне самостоятельно справиться увы не удается. Поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью. Задача следующая:

При регистрации каждого нового пользователя на сайте, в каталоге:

`site.ru/us/db/us/`

создается файл, типа:

`123456789`

с его данными. Название файла - это `id` пользователя. Такой файл состоит из 10 строк.

`us/db/list` - это файл, в котором перечисляются все зарегистрированные пользователи. Каждая строка - это отдельный пользователь. Этот файл формируется так:

`email*пароль*idпользователя`

В админке (`site.ru/admin/`) я создал файл `school.php`, в котором делаю вывод всех пользователей, в следующем виде:

`Пользователь` - `Строка №5` (из файла данных пользователя) в `input type=text...`

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в админке я мог менять значение `Строки №5` в файле с данными у каждого Пользователя в отдельности.

```
chdir("..");
$cat=array();
$d=opendir("us/db/us");
while(($e=readdir($d))!=false)
  {
    if($e =="." || $e ==".." || $e==".htaccess" || $e=="admin") continue;
    $cat[]=$e;
  }
closedir($d);
 
$data_e=array();
 
$file=file("us/db/list");
foreach($file as $line)
  {
      $expl=explode("*",$line);
      $data_e[$expl[2]]=$expl[0];
  }
 
  if(isset($_GET['school']) && in_array($_GET['school'],$cat))
    {
       $file=file("us/db/us/$_GET[school]");
       $f=fopen("us/db/us/$_GET[school]","w");
       for($n=0;$n<count($file);$n++)
         {
           fwrite($f,$file[5]."\r\n");
         }
       fclose($f);
 
       echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0; url=school.php>";
       exit();
    }
$text=file("us/db/us/$cat[$x]");
$rec=file("admin/db/us/$cat[$x]");


echo"<p>Пользователь: $text[1]</p>
       <form name='$cat[$x]' method='post'>
       <input name=school type=text value='$text[5]'>
       <button name=school type=submit value=Изменить>Изменить</button>
       </form>";
```

Пожалуйста, помогите справиться с поставленной задачей. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Чтобы справиться с этой задачей, надо выкинуть из головы всю эту ерунду и использовать нормальную базу данных.

Comment: Используя файл - вы напрягаете жесткий диск, перезаписывая весь файл заново - вы изнашиваете жесткий диск, используйте базу данных. Так как база данных выгружается в оперативку, поиск данных происходит быстрее , в том числе за счет индексации. Запись будет произведена с минимальными затратами ресурсов компьютера.

Comment: @Mcile открою вам маленький секрет: база данных тоже хранит данные в файлах, изнашивая диск, а файл тоже выгружается в оперативку. Это не те причины, по которым следует использовать БД. Причина в том, что код будет в 10 раз проще